# Map an excel sheet to auto import products and update inventory and prices

Tags: solidus

Is there a way to map an excel sheet to auto import products and update inventory and prices from sheet on Solidus??

Comment: Did you ever figure an answer out to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/solidusio-contrib/solidus_importer

You can export the data from Excel to CSV and than import it with this extension.